# How to determine UUDecoding method needed?

Tags: c#, encoding, uuencode, uudecode

I'm communicating to a device that returns uuencoded data:

**ASCII:** EZQAEgETAhMQIBwIAUkAAABj

**HEX:** 45-5A-51-41-45-67-45-54-41-68-4D-51-49-42-77-49-41-55-6B-41-41-41-42-6A

The documentation for this device states the above is uuencoded but I can't figure out how to decode it. The final result won't be a human readable string but the first byte reveals the number of bytes for the following product data. (Which would be 23 or 24?)

I've tried using Crypt2 to decode it; it doesn't seem to match 644, 666, 744 modes.

I've tried to hand write it out following the Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding#Formatting_mechanism

Doesn't make sense! How do I decode this uuencoded data?

Comment: I'd say that it is definitely not UUEncoded. UUEncoded data only uses upper case letters. Yours has lower case letters, so it's not UUEncoded. Maybe it's BASE64 encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @canton7 that it looks like it's base64 encoded. You can decode it like this

```
byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String("EZQAEgETAhMQIBwIAUkAAABj");
```

and if you want, you can print the hex values like this

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(decoded));
```

which prints

```
11-94-00-12-01-13-02-13-10-20-1C-08-01-49-00-00-00-63
```

Comment: @canton7 Nice. I didn't know that one. Thanks!

Comment: I've ran it through and checked it by hand.. it's definitely base64 encoded not uuencoded! Developers and their documentation ;) --You guys are legends! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

As @HansKilian says in the comments, this is not uuencoded.

If you base64-decode it you get (in hex):

> 11 94 00 12 01 13 02 13 10 20 1c 08 01 49 00 00 00 63

The first number, 17 in decimal, is the same as the number of bytes following it, which  matches:

> The final result won't be a human readable string but the first byte reveals the number of bytes for the following product data.

(@HansKilian made the original call that it was base64-encoded. This answer provides confirmation of that by looking at the first decoded byte, but please accept his answer)

Comment: I've ran it through and checked it by hand.. it's definitely base64 encoded not uuencoded! Developers and their documentation ;) --You guys are legends! Thank you :)